# Shared string constant in C++

Tags: c++, header, linker

I want to define a string constant that can be used by various classes.
So I created a header file and added:

```
namespace MyConstants
{
    extern const char* Constant1 = "SomeString";
}
```

This header gets included in several .cpp files from which I access the string.

This gives me the following linker error:

> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

How would I need to change the string's declaration to make this linker error go away?

Comment: I think you shouldn't assign value to variable in declaration.

Comment: This would be simpler if you put a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the value to be defined in just one translation unit, and leave a pure declaration in the headers.

```
namespace MyConstants
{
    extern const char* Constant1;
}
```

And in just one translation unit:

```
namespace MyConstants
{
    extern const char* Constant1 = "SomeString";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `constexpr`

```
// In header
namespace MyConstants
{
    constexpr const char* Constant1 = "SomeString";
}
```

or splitting declaration and definition

```
// In header
namespace MyConstants
{
    extern const char* Constant1;
}
```

And

```
// in one unique cpp.
namespace MyConstants
{
    extern const char* Constant1 = "SomeString";
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think using constexpr would fix it!  Have an upvote! :)